# Automatically create new entity when bound property changes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

I have an entity-based `NSObjectController` that is configured to use a "MyProperty" object it creates from a fetch request, like so:

```
@interface MyPropertyController : NSObjectController
@property (strong) NSString *propertyName;
@end

@implementation MyPropertyController

- (instancetype)initWithPropertyName:(NSString *)propName moc:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.propertyName = propName;

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"propertyName == %@", argumentArray:@[propName]];
        self.managedObjectContext = moc;
        self.entityName = @"MyProperty";
        self.fetchPredicate = predicate;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)newObject {
    MyProperty *prop = [super newObject];
    prop.propertyName = self.propertyName;
    return prop;
}

@end
```

In the `UI` I bind `MyProperty.numberValue` to a slider, so that the user can change the value of the sider:

```
MyPropertyController *controller = [[MyPropertyController alloc] initWithPropertyName:@"some user-specified name" moc:self.managedObjectContext];
NSSlider *slider = [[NSSlider alloc] init];
[slider bind:NSValueBinding toObject:controller withKeyPath:@"content.numberValue" options:@{ NSNullPlaceholderBindingOption : @0 }];
```

This all works find as long as the instance of `MyProperty` exists when the user is dragging the slider. However, I want to automatically create the instance of the property if the user drags the slider and the `MyProperty` instance does not yet exist.

Is this possible? The only way I've been able to accomplish it has been to use a custom `NSValueTransformer` that uses the `reverseTransformedValue` to manually create and insert an instance of the class, but I can't help but feel that there should be a proper way to do this in the `NSObjectController` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maybe solve this problem by using a container object as object for your object controller, which always exists. And this container object hold the entity in a property.

You can then overload the `setValue:forKeyPath:` and ensure that the entity gets created before you set the new value.

Another idea would be using a `NSProxy` for your entity, but this would be difficult to get it right with `KVO`.

Comment: I can also just work around it by overriding setValue:forKeyPath: in the NSObjectController subclass itself and lazily creating the property. But I feel like there simply must be a “right” way to do it.